# can't get simple agility.js to work

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, agility.js

I'm trying to learn agility.js and what I thought should be a simple exmaple, I can't get to work and I'm not sure why.  Clicking the button should change the text of the span to "Goodbye World" but clicking does nothing.  Any ideas?

```
var message = 
        $$(
            {txt:'Hello World'}, 
            {format:'<span data-bind="txt" /><button id="btn">Click Me</button>'}, 
            {'click #btn' : function(){ this.model.set({txt:"Goodbye World"}) }}
        );


$$.document.append(message);
```

Comment: when I moved the value of format into a script block with it's type set to text/html, given an id of 'viewcontent' and then set format: $('#viewcontent').html() it works.  I'm not sure why and that doesn't seem consistent with the examples.

Answer (score 4):

Try wrapping your format string in a single enclosing tag, like ... This is required for Agility to work properly, but Agility won't throw an error if it's missing.

I got your code working at this URL: http://jsbin.com/emacez/edit

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon

```
{'click #btn' : function(){ this.model.set({txt:"Goodbye World"}); }}    <----
```